Figure captions and numbering in Rmarkdown when rendering to html
When knitting my rmarkdown file as a pdf, the fig.cap option that I have set at the beginning of each chunk that creates a plot ends up being a nicely formatted piece of text, with automatically generated figure numbers, like the below:

However, when I try to knit to HTML, it instead just outputs the caption as raw, unformatted text. Such as below:

I have used both the vanilla .Rmd tools (i.e. knitr and rmarkdown), but also bookdown (outputting to a bookdown::html_document2) with no luck. Does anyone know how I can knit my .Rmd to a html file, whilst maintaining the nicely formatted figure captions and numbering?

The dup says to use bookdown::html_document2 and it worked for me when I tried their example.  If it's not working for you, you'll need to post code to illustrate what you tried.  It should be a complete document, but not your real document, just a sample doc.
